# Global Filter Migration from Spray to Akka-Http 2

Tags: akka, spray, akka-http, spray-dsl

I have a filter of route handler using Spray Custom Directive0.

The purpose of this custom directive is to build a request filter to time the request processing time.

Inside the **spray** custom directive, I can use the **RequestContext**'s function **withHttpResponseMapped** to take a parameter of **HttpResponse => HttpResponse**, and withHttpResponseMapped will return a new RequestContext object, like this:

```
 def timeRequestInterval: Directive0 = {
mapRequestContext { context =>
  val requestTimer = new RequestTimer(context.request)
  context.withHttpResponseMapped { response =>
    requestTimer.stop()
    response.mapEntity { entity =>
        entity
    }
  }
}
```

Now I try to migrate the custom directive from Spray to **Akka-Http(2.4.8)**, but ***I cannot find withHttpResponseMapped*** or any function in RequestContext object that can take parameter of "HttpResponse => HttpResponse" and return a new RequestContext object.  Is there any supported function or approach that can help me resolve this issue in Akka-Http Migration?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mapResponse` directive is what you are looking for and then combine the directives with `flatMap` rather than `apply`:

```
val timeRequestInterval: Directive0 = extractRequestContext.flatMap { context =>
  val timer = new RequestTimer(context)
  mapResponse { response =>
    timer.stop()
    response
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  Johan.  It works now.   Really appreciate your help.

Alan

Comment: I'm trying a very similar flow and instead getting the following error:
`type mismatch; [error]  found   : akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[Unit] required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]          extractRequestContext.flatMap { requestContext =>`